# CouchDB and Ruby on Rails Tutorials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, couchdb

I am very new to rails and couchdb and I am looking for good tutorials that describe how to create a project using the two technologies.

Does anyone has links to useful resources/tutorials?

Answer (score 7):

I could recommend you this article: http://mattscodecave.com/posts/getting-couchdb-to-work-with-couchrest-in-rails-4.html (UPDATED)

Also here is good step-by-step manual: http://railskey.wordpress.com/2013/07/10/rails-couchdb-demo-application/

Good luck with CouchDB.

Comment: The first link seems to be broken